# How to unit test that a project does not reference a specific assembly

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

We separate some interfaces in a library of its own and do not want that the libraries with the implementation are referenced directy in the calling project.

A: calling code project. 
B: interface project. 
C: implementation project

A should reference B but not C

We want to ensure this with a unit test.

What would a unit test look like with NUnit?

Comment: Can you shed a little more light on the situation? There is a library with interfaces. Obviously, the assemblies with some implementations reference this interface assembly. And you want to make sure that who is not referencing the implementation assemblies? Some (third) application assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't say I've ever done this. You could try using [Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is just to remember the unit test for my own usage. But feel free to upvote :-)

```
[Test]
public void ShouldNotReferenceServiceProjectDirectly()
{
    var assembly = GetAssemblyContainingType<RouteConfig>();
    var referencedAssemblies = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();

    var implementationAssembly = referencedAssemblies
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MyNamespace.Service");

    var interfaceAssembly = referencedAssemblies
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MyNamespace.Service.Interfaces");

    Assert.That(implementationAssembly, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(interfaceAssembly, Is.Not.Null);
}

private static Assembly GetAssemblyContainingType<T>()
{
    return (typeof(T).Assembly);
}
```

Comment: Trivial comment: To be more symmetric, you should use `referencedAssemblies` in the assignment to `interfaceAssembly`